# php appending inside foreach, what is the use of appending to a variable.

Tags: php

How to append the code to a variable.

```
<?php
echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach($related as $r) {

        if ($r->Count > 0) {
            echo "<li>" . "<a>". $r->post_title ."</a>". "\n";
      f_tree_av($r->post_id, $level + 1);
      echo "</li>";
        } elseif ($r->Count==0) {
            echo "<li>" . "<a>". $r->post_title ."</a>". "\n";
        } else;
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
?>
```

Comment: What do you want to append?  And what do you want to append it to?

Comment: To a variable. Eg: $content

Comment: Shortened syntax for `String1 = $string1.$string2` is `$string1 .= $string2;`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Instead of `echo` in the loop, do `$content .= "<li>....";` then output `$content` when you are ready to use it.

Comment: @AvinVarghese http://pastebin.com/2ZFzrMJ9

Comment: OK, Then why my question is down voted.

Comment: Possibly because you should already know that? As it is a part of basic knowledge you can get after ready any basic book. And answer could be easily found by googling "php append variable" First item in results: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Repeatedly tried and i got error that's why i asked here.

Comment: And why do you post a piece of code which is NOT related to your actual problem? Question should be: I have this code, but it throws me this error. How can I fix that?

Comment: That was the code i tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$content .= "<ul>\n";
    foreach($related as $r) {

        if ($r->Count > 0) {
            $content .= "<li>" . "<a>". $r->post_title ."</a>". "\n";
      f_tree_av($r->post_id, $level + 1);
      echo "</li>";
        } elseif ($r->Count==0) {
            $content .= "<li>" . "<a>". $r->post_title ."</a>". "\n";
        } else;
    }
   $content .= "</ul>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `.=` operator, which means `$a = $a . "...";` (`$a .= "..."` )

```
<?php
$content = "<ul>\n";
    foreach($related as $r) {

        if ($r->Count > 0) {
            $content .= "<li>" . "<a>". $r->post_title ."</a>". "\n";
      f_tree_av($r->post_id, $level + 1);
                  $content .= "</li>";
        } elseif ($r->Count==0) {
                        $content .= "<li>" . "<a>". $r->post_title ."</a>". "\n";
        } else;
    }
    echo $content . "</ul>\n";
?>
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)